# I am using carousel ander the toggle div but carousel images not showing propery

Tags: toggle

I am using carousel ander the toggle div but carousel images not showing properly.

Please see screenshot.

[[image: Toggle Problem]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I have added the image for you.  IT is still not clear what you are asking.  Please explain it in more detail.

Comment: carousel image size are reducing under toggle section.